# How to know which WMS URL to use in Tableau

Tags: maps, tableau-api, wms, noaa

I'm trying to layer WMS from NOAA in Tableau. How do I know which URL to use from the provided file?

[Provided File](https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/NWS_Forecasts_Guidance_Warnings/wpc_precip_hazards/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS)

[Background Info](https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Forecasts_Guidance_Warnings/wpc_precip_hazards/MapServer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first URL, the one with the WMS request to GetCapabilities has the right form (although you can usually optionally cutoff the URL right before the ? character) Tableau will add the GetCapabilities part of the request when needed if you don’t.

The problem is that it looks like NOAA’s server is not responding properly to that WMS request. You should see a response in XML format describing the server’s capabilities, layers etc

So I’d ask the people that own the server what is going on.